# I need to covernt 5'11" to CM with python code

Tags: python, sql, gis, database-cursor

I am working on a homework assignment that I need to take the heightfield in an attribute table and have it be converted to CM in another field. Right now I have:

```
 with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(position + ".shp", "height") as cursor:
    for row in cursor: heightcm = row[0] 
    height = heightcm.split("' ")
    feet = int(height[0])
    inches = int(height[1])
    cm = (12*feet + inches)* 2.54
    print(cm)
```

I know the format of 5'11" is messing up my split, but I am unsure how to fix this. Could anyone please help me.

I am getting a ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' 1"'

Answer (score 0):

To convert you could do this

```
for row in cursor: 
    heightcm = row[0] 
    height = heightcm.split("'")
    feet = int(height[0])
    inches = int(height[1][:-2])
    cm = (12*feet + inches)* 2.54
    print(cm)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the error in my 1st post, I edited in. I get ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' 1"' for the inches line. Your changes did not help the error. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @JackRosenblit updated it